# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). cant get this error out

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

tried a lot but cant figure out this error, im using script and ajax toolkit and i changed to <%= ...%> and also added page.header.databind() but no use

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

can any body please help me

and my stack trace is

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified    because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).]
   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +9871215
   AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control  control) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server  \AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptObjectBuilder.cs:323
  AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs:305
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: Can you also show the markup where you used inline code blocks ?

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
   
<%--    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
      <link href="<%# ResolveUrl("../Css/Parent/example.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
       <script src = "<%# ResolveUrl("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Page.Header.Databind()` does nothing if you don't have databinding expressions (`<%# %>`) in the header. The `<%= ...%>` is a code block, not the databinding expression. Just try to change it to `<%# ... %>` instead.